# How many concurrent connections can I allow to MySQL database for best performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, connection

I have installed MySQL server on Linux CentOS remote server. The **mysql -V** tells -

**mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.61, for redhat-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.1**

I have 2GB of RAM with 15 GB disk space. My Database size is 2GB with 12 tables from which one table of 20 Million records. This database is used for mobile application through **REST** webservice.

**So I want to know that How many concurrent connections can I allow to this database for best performance?**

I was told that there will be **100000** concurrent access to the database.

Please Gurus help me.

Thank You

Comment: By 1Lac do you mean 10^5 ?  If so, it might be useful to say so.  Many readers of SO will be unfamiliar with Lac (which is often written lakh).

Comment: ya its 1Lac means 100000 records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `MYISAM` tables then you can use following formula to calculate memory requirements:

```
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size) * max_connections = K bytes of memory
```

have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-use.html)

Comment: Thank you Omesh for quick reply I'll go through it. But how can I check performance for multiple concurrent connections